# Unions in C++11: default constructor seems to be deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unions

I am trying to understand how unions were extended by C++11. One thing that changed is the ability to use now non-static data members with non-trivial special member functions. From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (default constructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or destructor), that function is deleted by default in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.
> At most one data member can have a default member initializer.

I am trying the following code:

```
struct X
{
    ~X() {};
};

union U
{
    X x;
    ~U() {};
};

int main()
{
    U s1{};  // works, probably aggregate initialization
    U s2;    // DOES NOT compile, why?
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca4eb5bf342aa96b)

Here `X` (which is used as a data member of the union) has a user provided destructor, hence the destructor of the union is by default deleted. Therefore I provide one explicitly. However, the code fails to compile, with the error

> note: 'U::U()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

The code compiles if I remove the last line `U s2;`.

**Question** What is going on here? Why `U s1{};` compiles, but `U s2;` does not? Is the default ctor of the union marked as deleted (if so, why?!), and in the first case we have just aggregate initialization? Note that if I provide `U(){}; // not U() = default;` the code compiles (but not if I only provide a ctor of `X`).

**EDIT**

After digging into the standard (N4527):

**Unions: 9.5/2 [class.union]**

> [Note: If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. —endnote]

it seems that this is a gcc bug (now reported [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69131)). The code compiles on clang and gcc 4.8.2 or earlier, it breaks on gcc4.9 and later (thanks @T.C. for pointing out).

Compiler: g++5.3, `-std=c++11` used.

Comment: [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b58a360400009fa9) is perfectly happy with this code. This looks like a GCC bug to me, actually.

Comment: @T.C. Yes I actually saw this just now after your comment. I first had the impression clang was also rejecting it, may have been tested some modified version. Edited the last line of the question, thanks.

Comment: @T.C. I will try to dig into the standard...

Comment: Works on [GCC 4.8.2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LWdH23iMrXAVfVJe), breaks on 4.9.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I should have tried more compiler versions.

Comment: Now https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69131

Answer (score 4):

X is not a pod type because is not trivially copiable as it has a non-trivial destructor.

Also U is not a pod type.

`U s2;` 
try to call the default costructor that is deleted so the error

`U s1 {};`
use member wise initialization and don't call any costructor

In union with non-POD member the default costructor of union is deleted because it would call the default costructor of members ie the compiler doesn't know which member to call the default costructor

```
union XX{
   string m1; 
   vector <int> m2;
}
```

default costructor of XX cannot call default costructor of m1 AND m2 so it is deleted.

Comment: Agree with your statement, but what I did not understand is why the default constructor is deleted.

Comment: @vsoftco I add some explanation of what i think it appens

Comment: It may be the case, although I see no reason why the compiler cannot just call the constructor of the first member. Same as if you do `XX x{"test"};`, the compiler calls the ctor of `m1`, i.e. the ctor of the first member.

Comment: The root problem is that only one member can safely be in a "constructed" state at a time and you have to know which one it is to safely destroy the union. I guess they could have made the default to construct one element but they have no way of telling which element (if any) is the "right one" to construct Often a bad default can be worse than no default at all because it doesn't push people into thinking about things.

Answer (score 3):

The cppreference quote is unclear.  What happens is that if *ANY* memeber of the union defines *ANY* of those non-trivial special member functions, then *ALL* of them will be deleted by default in the union.

So since you have a non-trivial destructor for `X`, the `U` default constructor is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, if this is so then it makes perfect sense. And `U s1{};` works because we use aggregate initialization, right?

Comment: Mostly, yeah. The C++11 rules allow you to have more complex types in unions, but you have to manage calling their constructors and destructors manually based on whatever type tag you use in the object/function managing the union. Usually, this means using placement new/delete.

Comment: You have a quote? I don't think that's what the standard says.

Comment: **Unions: 9.5/2** *"[Note: If any non- static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. —endnote]"* So it seems only that specific function is deleted, not all of them. Probably a gcc bug.

Comment: @vsoftco I think, it is zero-initialization, see [dcl.init] 8.5\8.2