# B+ tree insertion and searching

Tags: c++, pointers, b-tree

I'm trying to implement insertion and searching of information in files using b+tree, while doing so im getting an error as undefined reference

I've made changes from the original code whose link is given below only the main.cpp and header file has been changed

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//#include <filesystem>
#include "BPTree.h"

void insertionMethod(BPTree** bPTree) {
    int rollNo;
    int age, marks;
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please provide the rollNo: ";
    std::cin >> rollNo;

    std::cout << "\nWhat's the Name, Age and Marks acquired?: ";
   std::cin >> name >> age >> marks;

    std::string fileName = "DBFiles/";
     fileName += std::to_string(rollNo) + ".txt";
    FILE* filePtr = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "w");
    std::string userTuple = name + " " + std::to_string(age) + " " + std::to_string(marks) + "\n";
    fprintf(filePtr, userTuple.c_str());
    //fclose(filePtr);

    (*bPTree)->insert(rollNo, filePtr);
    fclose(filePtr);
    std::cout << "Insertion of roll No: " << rollNo << " Successful"<<std::endl;
}

void searchMethod(BPTree* bPTree) {
    int rollNo;
    std::cout << "What's the RollNo to Search? ";
    std::cin >> rollNo;

    bPTree->search(rollNo);
}
int main() {
  
    bool flag = true;
    int option;

    int maxChildInt = 4, maxNodeLeaf = 3;
    std::cout << "Please provide the value to limit maximum child Internal Nodes can have: ";
    std::cin >> maxChildInt;
    std::cout << "\nAnd Now Limit the value to limit maximum Nodes Leaf Nodes can have: ";
    std::cin >> maxNodeLeaf;

    BPTree* bPTree = new BPTree(maxChildInt, maxNodeLeaf);
    std::cout<<bPTree->getMaxLeafNodeLimit()<<std::endl;
    do {
        std::cout << "\nPlease provide the queries with respective keys : " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tPress 1: Insertion \n\tPress 2: Search<< std::endl;
        std::cin >> option;

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                insertionMethod(&bPTree);
                break;
            case 2:
                searchMethod(bPTree);
                break;
            default:
                flag = false;
                break;
        }
    }while (flag);

    return 0;
}
```

BPTree.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
class Node {
   public:
    bool isLeaf;
    std::vector<int> keys;
  
    Node* ptr2next;              
    union ptr {                    
        std::vector<Node*> ptr2Tree;  //Array of pointers to Children sub-trees for intermediate Nodes
        std::vector<FILE*> dataPtr;   // Data-Pointer for the leaf node

        ptr();   // To remove the error !?
        ~ptr();  // To remove the error !?
    } ptr2TreeOrData;

    friend class BPTree;  // to access private members of the Node and hold the encapsulation concept
   public:
    Node(){
        this->isLeaf = false;
        this->ptr2next = NULL;
    }
};



class BPTree {
   private:
    int maxIntChildLimit;                                   //Limiting  #of children for internal Nodes!
    int maxLeafNodeLimit;                                   // Limiting #of nodes for leaf Nodes!!!
     Node* root;  Node* pparent = NULL;                                           //Pointer to the B+ Tree root
    void insertInternal(int x, Node** cursor, Node** child);  //Insert x from child in cursor(parent)
  Node** findParent(Node* cursor, Node* child){
       if (cursor->isLeaf || cursor->ptr2TreeOrData.ptr2Tree[0]->isLeaf)
        return NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < cursor->ptr2TreeOrData.ptr2Tree.size(); i++) {
        if (cursor->ptr2TreeOrData.ptr2Tree[i] == child) {
            pparent = cursor;
        } else {
            Node* tmpCursor = cursor->ptr2TreeOrData.ptr2Tree[i];
            findParent(tmpCursor, child);
        }
    }

    return &pparent;
  }


   public:
    BPTree();
    BPTree(int degreeInternal, int degreeLeaf){
        this->maxIntChildLimit = degreeInternal;
    this->maxLeafNodeLimit = degreeLeaf;
    this->root = NULL;
    }

    int getMaxIntChildLimit();
    int getMaxLeafNodeLimit() 
    {
        return maxLeafNodeLimit;
    }
    void search(int key);
    void insert(int key, FILE* filePtr);
   
};
#endif
```

[Search](https://github.com/niteshkumartiwari/B-Plus-Tree/blob/master/search.cpp)  and [Insert](https://github.com/niteshkumartiwari/B-Plus-Tree/blob/master/insertion.cpp) code

The error im getting is

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cctqZ0YA.o:insert.cpp:(.text$_ZN4NodeC1Ev[__ZN4NodeC1Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `Node::ptr::ptr()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not so sure what Node::ptr::ptr() is could someone help out

Comment: If I remove those two lines im getting a bunch of errors like `use of deleted function 'Node::ptr::ptr()'`

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get after deleting those declared but undefined constructor and destructor points to the actual problem. Why unions might need a constructor and destructor is better explained elsewhere, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26572240/1332041) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34581372/1332041).

You can get your code compiling by providing a trivial empty implementation.

```
ptr() {};
~ptr() {};
```

Comment: whats happening in this line `new (&root->TreeOrDataPtr.DataPtr) std::vector<FILE*>;` its inside the search file